# How to access Page object from Static method in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, webmethod

I have a website, wherein i have a dropdownlist, where i need to show the price of the package selected from the dropdownlist, as i have lots of products listed on the page and everyone has the package dropdown

i don't want to make postback on every selection of the package. so i would like to go with AJax jQuery implementation, i am using repeater control to show the list of products.

Below is the webmethod function which i am using:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static String FillLabel(int Index)
    {
    Page pa = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
            Repeater homeRepeater = pa.FindControl("rptProducts") as Repeater;
         DropDownList drpUnit = homeRepeater.FindControl("drpQuantity") as DropDownList;
                 int Unit = int.Parse(drpUnit.SelectedItem.Text.Split(' ')[0].Trim());
                 HiddenField productId = (homeRepeater.Items[Index].FindControl("hdProductId") as HiddenField);
                 Package objPackage = new Package();
                 objPackage.ProductId = Convert.ToInt32(productId.Value);
                 objPackage.TownId = Globals.DefaultTown;
                 Label mrp = (homeRepeater.Items[Index].FindControl("lblMRP") as Label);
                 Label ourPrice = (homeRepeater.Items[Index].FindControl("lblOurPrice") as Label);
                 Label discount = (homeRepeater.Items[Index].FindControl("lblDiscount") as Label);
                 double discountPercent = Convert.ToDouble(objPackage.GetProductPackages().Find(item => item.Unit == Unit && item.ProductsInfo.ProductID == objPackage.ProductId).Discount);
                 string mrpVal = objPackage.GetProductPackages().Find(item => item.Unit == Unit && item.ProductsInfo.ProductID == objPackage.ProductId).MaximumRetailPrice.ToString();
                 string price = objPackage.GetProductPackages().Find(item => item.Unit == Unit && item.ProductsInfo.ProductID == objPackage.ProductId).SabkaSupermarketPrice.ToString();
                 mrp.Text = mrpVal;
                 ourPrice.Text = price;
                 mrp.Visible = (mrpVal != price);
                 if (discountPercent > 0)
                 {
                     discount.Visible = true;
                     discount.Text = objPackage.GetProductPackages().Find(item => item.Unit == Unit && item.ProductsInfo.ProductID == objPackage.ProductId).Discount.ToString() + "%<br/> OFF";
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     discount.Visible = false;
                 }
       return String.Empty;
}
```

Now my problem is i am unable to find repeater control as the function is static and i can't access the page object to find repeater control.

Can anyone tell me how shall i access the repeater control in the static method?

Comment: You can not access from static, the page. You need to find a work around, if you make the call from inside the code behind page, send the page handler, if you make the call from javascript, get the return and change with javascript what is on page.

Answer (score 0):

i am pretty sure you dont have a Page object, nor its controls. your "current handler" is an ajax request.

if you must do it this way then you should use the AjaxPanel control which creates a full page cycle, meaning pageload and everything, then your AjaxPanel's method but the client itself feels a change as if it was an ajax request only.

Comment: Is there any other better approach i can go with

Comment: sending in the ajax call all the info you need and bring back all the info you need, using large objects ect.